# What is Interlocking about?

Tags: file-locking

Recently I ["fixed" issue with locking](https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2020-November/246887.html) when I access LXSS backed P9 network FS mounted in Cygwin by:

```
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

I read `(info "(emacs.info) Interlocking")` but still didn't get it.

Is it defense against simultaneous writing from another Emacs? Or general outside edits?

Is it the "fancy" way to save file's timestamp?

Is it make sense to use this feature from Cygwin Emacs (which emulated symlink API)?

I believe that Emacs is doing mtime check (what about fsize??) anyway and this "symlink" business looks stupid...

Comment: I should mention that those `.#` files/symlinks are distracting as hell. Other tools show them and I didn't know the reason of these files for 10 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are a protection against simultaneous editing by two Emacs sessions, yes. This can even be between instances of Emacs running on different computers, which can happen when both computers can access the same file system over the network. This was a more frequent occurrence when dozens or hundreds of people would log into the same computer. The symlink contains the username and process id of the Emacs session specifically so that you can go to their office/lab/desk/etc and ask them if they are done with the file or not.

Most tools can be configured to ignore them. For example, if you add these rules to your Git repository's `.gitignore` file, git commands will ignore them:

```
*~
.\#*
```

It's been so long since I've used Cygwin that I can't say with certainty whether or not it's useful there. Honestly, I would just use the native Windows builds of Emacs, even if I was using Cygwin to provide other command-line tools.

Comment: I'm using Emacs server so there is no situation when I need it. It just created half an hour obstacle for me... Probably documentation should be more clear on that it is limited to Emacs only...